# Why does the 74LS32N behave like an AND gate?

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-gates, ttl, logic-level

[image]First of all I am a beginner.
I am practicing with the 74LS32N (OR Gate) IC , I noticed that it behaves like an AND gate instead of an OR Gate.

Only when both the inputs are 1 , the output is 1 , (Led will light up)

What have I done wrong here ?[image]

Comment: Check power supply connections and bypass caps. Since it is an LS TTL amily chip, the 10k pull-down resistor makes little sense. It would be fine with CMOS inputs, but with LS TTL, the buttons should pull low and the resistor should pull high and have lower value like 4.7k. LS chips also can't source out a lot of current to drive the LED, but it can sink in a lot more.

Comment: Have you tried a different 7432?

Comment: @Justme thanks for the advice , I changed the resistance but the result is the same

Comment: @HandyHowie , yes

Comment: Can you add a photo of the constructed circuit?

Comment: Sure @HandyHowie

Comment: I just constructed exactly the same circuit as yours and it worked correctly.  You could try pulling all the unused inputs down to ground, just to ensure they are not causing an issue.

Comment: Can you also check that you have 5v across pins 14 and 7 by putting your meter directly on the pins?

Comment: @HandyHowie , I have 4.98V between pin 14 and 7. I pulled down all the other inputs to ground as well. Still no luck.

Comment: I even replaced with all the other 74ls32 chips , all of them responded in the same manner as the chip in the picture above did , maybe I bought faulty chips

Comment: Have you tried using different gates on the same IC?

Comment: Where did you get them from?

Comment: @HandyHowie , yes I tried using different Gates of the same IC , the outcome is the same , I got them from a local electronics store , I even switched up IC's (with other 74ls32 IC's I had already) the result was same , thank you for helping out !

Comment: You could try just hard wiring one input as a 0 and the other as a 1, removing the switches and pull down resistors and seeing what results you get then.

Comment: @HandyHowie , I tried that too , thank you. I think the chips are faulty

Answer (score 1):

74LS TTL needs more than 10K for a pulldown. If you measure the input voltage without the buttons pressed, it is probably around 4V. A 1k pulldown would be more successful.

The reason is that the LS TTL input sources current - something like 400uA. Ohms law tells us V = I x R. 400uA x 10000 = 4V.

Try with 1k. 400uA x 1000 = 0.4V.

Or use 74HC/HCT chips.

Comment: how does this explain it acting like an and?

Comment: @Jasen - good question. I dare say there are other factors involved. Fix the obvious defects and see where that leads.

Comment: @Jasen I will repost this

Comment: @Kartman I tried with 1k and 10k both, I got no new result